# insertar valores en una tabla con un select

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo inserto valores en la base de datos?

Esto es una consulta, relaciona varias tablas, pero necesito que esos datos me queden almacenados en la **base de datos MySQL**

Ésta es la tabla que estoy haciendo en **PHP**

```
echo '<table id="TablaColor" border="1" width="100%">
                <tr id="TituloRojo">
                    <td colspan="8">Incumplimiento del Horario</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="TituloVerde">
                    <td colspan="1" width="100">Profesor</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Curso</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Día <br> evaluación</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Error <br> Nota</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Error <br> Trabajo</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Horario Entrada</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Tiempo de entrega</td>
                    <td colspan="1">Anotaciones</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$Nombre.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$curso.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$Dia.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1" id="TituloClaro">'.$Nota.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1" id="TituloClaro">'.$Trabajo.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$Entrada.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$Tiempo.'</td>
                    <td colspan="1">'.$Anotaciones.'</td>

                 </tr>
      </table>';
```

**¿EL INSERT DEBE IR ANTES O DESPUÉS DE LA TABLA?**

Comment: intentastes el `insert into tabla (valor1,valor2,valor3) (Tu select)`

Comment: Me da la impresión de que hay un problema de planteamiento o de comprensión, lo digo porque veo un `SELECT` dentro de un `SELECT` y hablas de una _tabla_ la cual según he entendido es una tabla PHP/HTML. ¿Lo que quieres no será seleccionar datos de una base de datos y presentarlos en tu página? O al revés, ¿tienes datos en tu página que quieres insertar en la base de datos?

Comment: Tengo datos en mi página que necesito insertar en la base de datos

Comment: tu pregunta es como mostrar los datos en una tabla html del query que estas realizando?

Comment: A ver, la tabla ya la tengo, ya la estoy mostrando. Necesito que los valores **que ya estoy mostrando en la tabla de php** queden almacenados en la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solucion es un **`insert/select`**   te colocare un pequeño ejemplo:

```
insert into tabla_replica (id_tabla1,nombre,apellido)
select id_tabla1,
       nombre,
       apellido
  from tabla1
  where id_tabla1 > 1;
```

para ver la funcionalidad completa te invito a ver este [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e072/1)

Comment: Si, ¿pero para éste ejemplo cómo sería porque es insertar los valores de una consulta de mysql a una tabla en mysql?

Comment: Estoy haciendo una consulta de MYSQL y una tabla en PHP, ¿Eso iría debajo de la tabla o antes de la tabla?

Comment: Aparte de eso ¿Se necesita un contador o no?

Comment: tu pregunta es hacer un insert con un select, creo que debes hacer otra

Comment: lo que puedes hacer luego de hacer el insert/select, hacer el select de la tabla replica

Comment: Es que la consulta ya la tengo y me está imprimiendo en la pantalla, lo único que me falta es que esos valores queden almacenados en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Pero debe ser dentro del while?

Comment: ¿Y necesito un contador o solamente con el while?

Comment: nada de eso solo ejecutar la consulta que esta en la respuesta y mysql se encarga de hacer lo demas, ahora si entendi lo del contador

Comment: ¿osea que para mi tabla cómo sería? Es que la verdad soy un poco nuevo en todo esto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63792/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-ceortiz).